# PostgreSQL: PL/R does not work as expected

Tags: sql, r, postgresql, plr

Using [this](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgresql_plr_tut01) tutorial of BostonGIS, I installed PL/R as an extension in my PostgreSQL 9.5 (x64) DB at Windows 7 Enterprise (x64) machine. After installation, I tested PL/R by running:

```
SELECT * FROM plr_environ();
```

and it returned environment information. Then, I ran:

```
SELECT load_r_typenames();
```

and the command took 5 minutes (and counting..) and never executed completely. I was unsure that  if something is messed up or how long this query should take. Thus, in another SQL editor, I tried following piece of code (source: [here](http://www.irsae.no/courses-conferences-and-workshops/upcoming-courses/next-generation-data-management-in-movement-ecology-a-summer-school-at-fem/there-and-back-again-part-iii-extending-postgis-with-plr/)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION plr_fn()
RETURNS float8 AS
$BODY$
  x <- 10
  4/3*pi*x^3
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plr'
```

Then, I called this function using:

```
SELECT plr_fn();
```

Again, the query took forever and was never completed. I am bit puzzled that what went wrong in PL/R installation as I followed all steps and set the environment variables. Can someone help me to understand what is wrong with my PL/R installation?

Comment: Open another session and see if something is blocking your query.

select * from pg_stat_activity where waiting; etc

Comment: Thanks. The query returned nothing.

Comment: Huh. Well if it's just hanging forever with no blocks, then I don't know what to do. I'd post to the pgsql-general mailing list (or search it through at postgresql.org for previous mentions).

Comment: Well in that case I could also try posting to mailing list. Thanks for your help anyways.

Comment: Yeah pl/r is specialized enough you're gonna need to find the two people who understand it etc. :)